# How to use CKEditor4 Upload Image using CDN?

Tags: image, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to enable the [Upload Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/uploadimage) drag and drop feature for CKEditor4. We have it hosted on our CDN at my job, and I've been adding plugins by simply adding them to the /plugins folder, and enabling them using `config.extraPlugins`.

The documentation for the file manager ([Image Uploader](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/imageuploader)) says to use `config.UploadUrl` to handle the image file upload. After adding the `uploadimage` folder to the CDN, I tried this, and nothing seems to happen. No errors in the console either.

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
CKEDITOR.config.UploadUrl = 'https://cdn.cpscentral.com/js/ckeditor4-fuller/imageuploader/imgupload.php';
```

It also says ***Don't forget to set CHMOD writable permission (0777) to the imageuploader folder on your server.*** I'm not entirely sure how to do this, but I know that this s3 folder is public. Would really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: The plugin is called imageuploader NOT uploadimage as you have CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage'; See my answer below.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I linked both. uploadimage is the drag and drop feature, and imageuploader is just the file that handles the file upload

Comment: If you follow my instructions, do you get a minimal working example?

Comment: I would like to use the existing CDN we have, instead of placing the files in the root of the website. When I try to do that, and follow your steps, I get: `Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "imageuploader" was not found at "https://cdn.cpscentral.com/js/ckeditor4-fuller/plugins/imageuploader/plugin.js?t=J6IA".`

Comment: Do you have the plugin unzipped in that folder? What is t=J6IA?

Comment: Yes, I have it properly added to the CDN, just as you have it in your root. I do not know what `t=J6IA` is. It was added to the end of the link within that error message. My `UploadUrl` is just that link without that ending, as you can see in my original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199589/discussion-between-shmob-and-hassan-voyeau).

Comment: Hi. Any updates on this?

Comment: I've been busy at my job, hopefully I can try it soon, I will update this post when I try it

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get a working example

- download ckeditor_4.12.1_full.zip
- unzip and copy contents to /ckeditor folder in root of website
- download imageuploader_4.1.8.zip
- unzip and copy contents to /ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader folder of
  website

This is my index.php

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my /ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader';
    config.UploadUrl = '/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgupload.php';
};
```

And the results

[image: Browse Server]